# Verification of scientific knowledge other than peer review?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, scientific-method

[Peer review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer_review#History) has been used for regulation of scientific knowledge for almost 350 years. Were there any common mechanisms for verification and regulation of scientific knowledge before peer review became widespread? Are there any other methods of verification of scientific knowledge commonly used now?

Comment: If one considers knowledge to be more than the papers they're written in, then: experience, experiment, formal/informal discussion, the process of application, and then some others which are usually considered less desirable, such as whether they fit in with various agendas or preconceptions. This list is incomplete.

Comment: @Lucas: Yeah, I wasn't sure how to deal with that in the question. I guess I'm looking for methods that are at least somewhat formalised, but I'm not sure - that may defeat the purpose of the question, which is really about whether there are any viable alternatives to peer review (I think that question would be too broad though).

Comment: I guess the answer to that would depend a lot on what you think peer review is supposed to achieve.

Comment: My understanding is that the intention behind peer review, ultimately (that is, in the science-for-the-greater-good sense, rather than in the let's-make-sure-that-this-article-is-correct sense), is to attempt to improve the reliability of the knowledge expressed. That is, to examine evidence and reasoning for flaws, as well as to ensure that the language (or graphics, or what ever other means of communication) used adequately conveys the knowledge that is intended to be conveyed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan: in what way?

Comment: @naught101 Those are empirical questions. Why do you think they have anything (essential) to do with philosophy?

Comment: I don't really see how the question is empirical. I'm asking if there are alternative methods of reinforcing the scientific method, which is one of the foremost ways of discovering reliable knowledge about the world. Surely the scientific method is fundamentally a matter for philosophic discussion?

Comment: I think this is a perfectly applicable question. In essence asking about how we get truth in science, What it means for scientific knowledge to be true and so on.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan: Yes, this is a question for http://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Neil is right. I was too impatient with this. If read in a very charitable way, there are excellent general philosophy of science/epistemology questions there. Retracting my vote to close.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan: Cool. Feel free to suggest ways to improve the question - I was aware that I was perhaps being a bit too vague when I first wrote it.

Comment: @Geremia: This question is asking about methods of knowledge improvement that fall outside of peer review. Pretty much all of academia uses peer review as the main method to improve knowledge, so I think this question would be more off-topic there than here (it has no current *practical* benefit to an academic).

Comment: @naught101 have you ran many things through peer-review? People who haven't tend to have a very inflated view of its usefulness. Peer-review wasn't developed to "verify scientific knowledge", it was originally developed to help journal editors select articles that were more likely to be of interest to their readers.

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev: not many, but some. I know that article selection is part of the reason for peer review, although I would be interested in a source for the claim that that was why it was originally developed. It's quite possible that verification is not the best word to use in the situation. Feel free to suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

Before 350 years ago, published academic works derived from lectures, repetitions, or disputations ([source](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/15188a.htm)):

> In all the faculties the work of teaching centred about books, i.e.
>   the texts, compilations, and glosses which were regarded as the chief
>   authorities in each subject. At the beginning of the year (or
>   semester) the books were distributed among the professors, who were
>   [obliged](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/11189a.htm) to use them in
>   accordance with the regulations established by each faculty regarding
>   the daily schedule, the length of the course, the hall to be used, the
>   academic dress to be worn, and the method to be followed. The lecture
>   was in the strict sense a *praelectio* (whence the German
>   *Vorlesung*); the professor had to read the text; in the ordinary lectures, he was not allowed to dictate anything beyond the divisions
>   and conclusions and such corrections of the text as he deemed
>   [necessary](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/10733a.htm). The scholars
>   were supposed to have their own copies of the text; if they were too
>   poor to procure the books, the professor might dictate the text to
>   them, not in the regular lecture but at special classes or exercises
>   (repetitions). The plan of the lecture was analytic: careful
>   explanation and definition of terms (*ponere et determinare*);
>   division of the matter and discussion of the several points followed
>   by a summary of the essential (*scindere et summare*); presentation of
>   problems suggested by the text (*quaestiones*), and solution of
>   objections. In lectures on law the reading of the glosses was an
>   important feature, and cases were frequently proposed to illustrate
>   principles. At the ordinary lectures, the scholars were not supposed
>   to ask questions; at the extraordinary, greater freedom was permitted,
>   the scholars being encouraged to express their
>   [doubts](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/05141a.htm) as to the meaning
>   of the texts and to request further information on obscure matters.
>   More thorough training, however, was given in the resumption and
>   repetitions which the masters held at stated times for the treatment
>   of special problems. The exercises, conducted in
>   [dialectical](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/04770a.htm) form,
>   afforded full opportunity for discussion between scholar and master;
>   and they served as examinations by which the progress of the scholar
>   was tested. But the most important of the academic exercises was the
>   disputation. This was of two kinds: *d. ordinaria* and *d. de
>   quodlibet*. The ordinary disputation took place every week and lasted
>   from morning till noon, or till evening according to the number of
>   participants. On the day set apart for this purposes the lectures and
>   other exercises were suspended, so that all the masters, bachelors,
>   and scholars might be present at the disputation. One of the masters
>   (*disputans*) announced, in the form of question or thesis, the
>   subject of the debate; other masters (*opponentes*) presented
>   arguments against the thesis; answers to the arguments were given by
>   two or three bachelors (*respondentes*) appointed for the occasion.
>   The number of arguments were fixed by statute or was fixed by the dean
>   of the faculty whose
>   [duty](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/05215a.htm) it was to preside.
>   Throughout the disputation the syllogistic form was employed. The
>   *disputation de quodlibet* was held only once a year, but with greater solemnity than the ordinary, and over a wider range of topics. The
>   master elected or appointed for the occasion, and known as the
>   *quodlibetarius*, had to debate a separate question with each of the other masters who chose to enter the lists. The disputation lasted
>   several days, sometimes a fortnight. The arguments and their solutions
>   were written out and preserved in book form. A specimen may be found
>   in the "Quodlibetales" of [St.
>   Thomas](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/14663b.htm). It was mainly out
>   of these lectures, repetitions, and disputations that the works of the
>   [medieval](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/10285c.htm)
>   [doctors](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/05072b.htm) grew; so that
>   the various commentaries, *summae*, and books of "sentences" afford
>   the best [idea](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07630a.htm) of
>   university teaching both as to content and as to method.

Disputations could be thought of as a public, open, oral form of peer review because they laid out all the arguments for and against a particular thesis, distilling out the truth.

Also, European universities were under the control of the Catholic Church, which had ultimate say what was taught at the universities, what textbooks could be used, etc. See, e.g., the [Condemnations of 1277](http://moerwiki.us.to/misc/Res%20pro%20Deo/Condemnation%20of%201277/The%20Condemnation%20of%201277,%20God%27s%20Absolute%20Power,%20and%20Physical%20Thought%20in%20the%20Late%20Middle%20Ages%20%28Edward%20Grant%29.pdf), which liberated the universities from intransigent Aristotelianism.

Answer (score 2):

[Scholasticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scholasticism) heavily relied on the critical reading of (and rigorous debate about) existing texts.

It emphasized authority rather than individual research, but the important thing that was lacking was *experimentation* as the ultimate arbiter of research.

And I think that is something that even today is often overlooked (if not outright neglected) in the peer review process of natural sciences: if you've read through a paper and thoroughly analyzed the autors' methods and reasoning, you may have ensured that certain kinds of errors and dishonesty are not present, but you still *haven't actually verified anything* until you've replicated their experimental results!

Comment: Interesting. Are you aware of any modern critiques of scholasticism? Would be cool to add a few points to that effect to this answer.

Comment: @naught101: haven't read academic critiques, though the surely exist. A very relavat quote from Goethe's *Faust* comes to mind, but it suffers in translation and in any case is ironic and thus easy to misinterpret.

Comment: @naught101: Kant wrote against what he called the "monopoly of the Schools," as he called Scholasticism. See [_Critique of Pure Reason_, intro. B32](https://archive.org/stream/immanuelkantscri032379mbp#page/n51/mode/2up)-5 (Kemp Smith's trans.) or [Guyer's trans.](http://catholicforum.fisheaters.com/index.php/topic,3463529.msg33956801.html#msg33956801)

Comment: "…in natural science they [the Scholastics] taught very emphatically that the argument from authority is the weakest of all arguments" ([source](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/13548a.htm)). In the natural sciences, the Scholastics _did_ do experiments; see the section "Albert and the experimental sciences" [here](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/01264a.htm), [this book](https://encrypted.google.com/books?id=nnqHZr3Rh5IC&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false), or [this article on the meaning of the word _experimentum_](http://www.thomist.org/jourl/2012/2012%20January/2012%20Jan%20A%20Barker.pdf).